# Azure YAML ARM Template - Pass $Build to PowerShell Script

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-rm-template

I currently have a working YAML ARM Template with the following:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Do My Stuff"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      pwsh: true
      filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Do-MyStuff.ps1'
      arguments: >- 
        -SourcesDirectory $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        -Foo hello
        -Bar world
```

But now I want to access additional properties of the $Build variable but when I do

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Do My Stuff"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      pwsh: true
      filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Do-MyStuff.ps1'
      arguments: >- 
        -Build $(Build)
        -Foo hello
        -Bar world
```

*(and update Do-MyStuff.ps1)*

I get the error:
`Build : The term 'Build' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Does anybody know what I can do to make it so I can pass $Build to my PowerShell Script?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that ARM considers `Build.` to just be part of the variable's name.
It is ***NOT*** a structure.

If you want to pass in multiple values, you can do something like this:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Do My Stuff"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      pwsh: true
      filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Do-MyStuff.ps1'
      arguments: >- 
        -Build @{
          'SourcesDirectory' = '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)';
          'ArtifactStagingDirectory' = '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)';
        }
        -Foo hello
        -Bar world
```

And the script would take a parameter something like:

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [hashtable]
    $Build,
```